# What's difference between this two jqpl requests?

Tags: sql, hibernate, persistence, jpql

I am creating JPQL database request. I have a super class and two subclasses;

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@Inheritance( strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED )
public class SuperClass(){

@Column(columnDefinition = "INTEGER")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

// others attributes/getters and setters

}
```

The subclasses :

```
@Entity
public class First extends SuperClass{
// attributes, getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class Second extends SuperClass{
// attributes, getters and setters
}
```

I am building a JPQL Query to fetch in database just result of First class. I notice something strange. I could miss something about JPQL.

```
String finalQuery = "SELECT distinct sup from SuperClass sup where sup.class =:myType";
Query query = em.createQuery(finalQuery);
query.setParameter("myType",First);
```

Here i am getting an exception :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [First] was not matching type [java.lang.Integer]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractQueryImpl.registerParameterBinding(AbstractQueryImpl.java:360) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.8.Final.jar:3.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.setParameter(QueryImpl.java:364) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.8.Final.jar:3.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.setParameter(QueryImpl.java:72) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.8.Final.jar:3.6.8.Final]
```

But if i write

```
String finalQuery = "SELECT distinct sup from SuperClass sup where sup.class =First";
    Query query = em.createQuery(finalQuery);
    List<PublishableElement> resultList = query .getResultList();
```

And no error. Why ? Is it not possible to pass the class type dynamicaly? 
I don't know really what's happen. I think it's on one of this lines:

```
Query query = em.createQuery(finalQuery);
    query.setParameter("myType",First);
```

Thanks

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807608/how-to-create-an-instance-of-like-query-in-jpa-2-0

Answer (score 1):

You have created 3 classes - `SuperClass`,`First`, `Second` and these classes have inheritance strategy of type `InheritanceType.JOINED`, so they do not have any discriminator column and its corresponding discriminator values. The below explanation is applicable only for scenario where the inheritance classes do not have any discriminator value to differentiate between classes.

Now, When you perform any select queries on these classes, what hibernate will do is it will check the hibernate configuration file (`hibernate.cfg.xml`) and assigns an integer to each class based on the order in which the entities are declared in configuration file.

For example:

If `hibernate.cfg.xml` file has entities declared in this order:

```
<mapping class="package.SuperClass"/>
<mapping class="package.Second"/>
<mapping class="package.First"/>
```

then hibernate assigns these numbers to the entities:

```
SuperClass - 0
Second - 1
First - 2
```

similarly if the entities are declared like this:

```
<mapping class="package.SuperClass"/>
<mapping class="package.Second"/>
<mapping class="package.First"/>
```

then the numbering will be

```
SuperClass - 0
First - 1
Second - 2
```

### First Query:

```
String finalQuery = "SELECT distinct sup from SuperClass sup 
                     where sup.class =:myType";

Query query = em.createQuery(finalQuery);
query.setParameter("myType",First);
```

in this HQL you want to filter the results based on class type. Based on my above explanation each class is assigned an integer, **so if you want to send it as a parameter then the parameter that you pass in `query.setParameter()` should be an integer.** If you want the SuperClass then you need to pass the integer value as `0` (assuming that SuperClass is declared first among the inheritance classes in hibernate.cfg.xml file).

So the variable `First` that you pass must be an integer.

**Note:**  Passing a String, eg: "First" to the `setParameter` will not work as Hibernate expects an integer in this case.

### Second Query:

```
String finalQuery = "SELECT distinct sup from SuperClass sup 
                      where sup.class =First";

Query query = em.createQuery(finalQuery);
List<PublishableElement> resultList = query .getResultList();
```

In this query you are directly telling that you need classes of type `First` as a String, this query is parsed by Hibernate, now hibernate knows how to map this string First to its corresponding integer and prepare the `SQL select` query from the given `HQL`.

So that is the reason you are getting exception with first HQL query but not with the second HQL query.