# How to check discriminator type in named query in jpa eclipse link

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I want to check discriminator type in jpa named query like any other attribute.

How can I check?

Answer (score 1):

Use TYPE in JPA 2.0:
   "select p from Employee e join e.projects p where type(p) = LargeProject"

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Criteria API: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Criteria
But this would be quiet overkill.

Use the JPA `TYPE()` so a Query could look like this:

```
SELECT s FROM Superclass s WHERE TYPE(s) = Superclass
```

This will compare the value set as DiscriminatorValue, so it acts like `instanceof`.

see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/7808003/5267377